# i2c-hid i2c-SYN1B7B:01:01 failed to retrieve report from device - problem during boot, device stops booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, swap

My laptop is configured to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. Windows 8 works fine, but when I try to boot into Ubuntu, sometimes, boot gets stuck at:

```
i2c-hid i2c-SYN1B7B:01:01 failed to retrieve report from device
```

However, if I hard reset a few times, my laptop seems to boot fine. I recently changed my swap partition, but did nothing else. Could that be what's causing the problem?

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue with kernel versions prior to 3.14 (see bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305522)).  Try updating to the most recent kernel and see if that fixes your problem.  (If you don't know how to do that, see askubuntu page [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)).

Additionally, I am fairly sure that messing with your swap partition caused this problem, as that shouldn't change the behavior of HID over I2C (my knowledge on this is rudimentary, though, so if anyone knows better feel free to correct me).